# Unity Battleships - Change the Color of a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

for school I want to create a small Battleships game. I want to hover the cells with the OnMouseEnter event but nothing happens, the event is never called.

I divided the Code into 3 Scripts, Data, Controller and View.

My Data keeps the information:

```
public class CellCommonData : MonoBehaviour // Datastore
{
    public bool IsShipCell { get; set; } // is a ship there?

    public bool WasActivated { get; set; } // cell already clicked

    [SerializeField]
    private Color defaultColor; // default Color -> light blue

    public Color DefaultColor { get { return defaultColor; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private Color mouseOverColor; // hover Color -> dark blue

    public Color MouseOverColor { get { return defaultColor; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private Color hitColor; // hit Color -> green

    public Color HitColor { get { return defaultColor; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private Color noHitColor; // no Hit -> red

    public Color NoHitColor { get { return defaultColor; } }

    private void Start()
    {
        WasActivated = false; // the cell is not clicked on Start
    }
}
```

My Controller will handle the Players actions:

```
public class CellCommonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CellCommonData cellData;
    private CellCommonView cellView;

    private void Start()
    {
        cellData = GetComponent<CellCommonData>();
        cellView = GetComponent<CellCommonView>();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown() // Cell clicked
    {
        if (!cellData.WasActivated) // Cell was not clicked before
        {
            if (cellData.IsShipCell) // ship hit?
            {
                cellView.SetCellColor(cellData.HitColor);
            }
            else // No ship there
            {
                cellView.SetCellColor(cellData.NoHitColor);
            }
            cellData.WasActivated = true; // Cell got clicked
        }
    }
}
```

And the View handles the "look" of the cell:

```
public class CellCommonView : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CellCommonData cellData;
    private Renderer cellRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        cellData = GetComponent<CellCommonData>();
        cellRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        SetCellColor(cellData.DefaultColor); // colorize the cell with the default Color
    }

    public void SetCellColor(Color color) // Change the cells color
    {
        cellRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", color);
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter() // cell got hovered
    {
        if (!cellData.WasActivated) // not clicked
        {
            SetCellColor(cellData.MouseOverColor);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseExit() // leave the cell
    {
        if (!cellData.WasActivated) // not clicked
        {
            SetCellColor(cellData.DefaultColor);
        }
    }
}
```

My only problem is, that the events `OnMouseEnter()` and `OnMouseExit()` are never called. But I do not get, what is wrong there.

Here is a picture of it:

[image: SceneView]

Comment: You aren't mousing over anything when you are calling that method, you have to have it in relation to what you are mousing over

Comment: Put Debug.Log in both `OnMouseEnter()` and `OnMouseExit()` before saying that they are not called.

Comment: Why would you make your model class a MonoBehaviour? And your problem is most likely lack of 3d collider component on this gameobject.

Comment: @Programmer Of course I put in Debug.Log.

Comment: @n_palum, could you explain it to me please =?

Comment: Like what @JerrySwitalski said - you don't have any sort of collider, so you are mousing over something, but it doesn't have any way to tell that it is there

Comment: What type of Object are you clicking on? Sprites? UI Image Component or 3D Object? A screenshot with it selected would be helpful.

Comment: I just updated my post with a picture :) The object is a 3d primitive cube.

Comment: Do you have a Physics Raycaster component in your camera?

Comment: Well ... suddenly the Event gets called ... seriously I just uploaded it to Github lol ... But the Color is not changed. The method is used at all times, but the Color does not change. But cellRenderer.material.color = color; seems right to me, no?

Answer (score 1):

The error is in CellCommonData.cs, all the getters return `defaultColor` instead of their appropriate backing fields, like this:

```
public class CellCommonData : MonoBehaviour // Datastore
{
    public bool IsShipCell { get; set; } // is a ship there?

    public bool WasActivated { get; set; } // cell already clicked

    [SerializeField]
    private Color defaultColor; // default Color -> light blue

    public Color DefaultColor { get { return defaultColor; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private Color mouseOverColor; // hover Color -> dark blue

    public Color MouseOverColor { get { return mouseOverColor; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private Color hitColor; // hit Color -> green

    public Color HitColor { get { return hitColor; } }

    [SerializeField]
    private Color noHitColor; // no Hit -> red

    public Color NoHitColor { get { return noHitColor; } }

    private void Start()
    {
        WasActivated = false; // the cell is not clicked on Start
    }
}
```